# passing repeated input elements values to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form where there are repeated input elements. For creating repeating elements I took reference from, [Dynamically repeat and remove form elements using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829026/dynamically-repeat-and-remove-form-elements-using-jquery).

In the form, there is text box for entering patient name and the repeating elements are inside div. The repeating elements are for inserting pharmacy records.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Patient Name:</div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PatientName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
</div>
    
 @*============ repeating element ================*@
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12"><b>Pharmacy</b></div>
        <div class="container-repeatable-elements">
            <span></span>
            <div class="form-list">
                <div id="form-template">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Medicine:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownList("MedicineId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="control-label col-md-2">Amount:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Amount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn add-btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm ml-1 add-repeatable-element-button">+ New Item</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    @*===============================================*@
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function addFormElements() {
        $('.form-list').append($("#form-template").clone())
    }

    function removeFormElements() {
        $(this).parents('.form-row').remove();
    }
    $(document).on("click", ".add-btn", addFormElements);
    $(document).on("click", ".remove-btn", removeFormElements);

</script>
```

**How to pass this repeating element data to controller method?** I have not done this case before so I do not have any idea and I did not find any information in this topics too.

When I did inspect element, I found that all the repeating elements have same id and same name too.

Comment: Make sure your element names match the expected format: [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/aspnet-wire-format-for-model-binding-to-arrays-lists-collections-dictionaries)